# Troubleshooting reboot of Mac OS X Snow Leopard server running mysql

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

we are using Mac OS X Snow Leopard server for mysql database, and it reboots once in a while. This happened once every month for the past 3 months. I looked at syslog and dmesg and I don't see any errors just before the reboot. How should I go about diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have enabled core dumps and the problem no longer happens.